# Is that okay to have the Disk type "Microsoft basic data" in Ubuntu

Tags: disk, fdisk, disk-management

- I was having Windows 11 and now I'm using Linux Ubuntu only. I have
  two disks **(SSD - HDD)**.
- My first SSD /dev/sdb disk has 2 partitions 1 with    Name **" EFI
  System Partition" ( FAT (32-bit version))**     And another partition **"
  Linux FileSystem " Ext4 (version 1.0)** GUID Partition Table

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 250068991 249018368 118.7G Linux filesystem
```

- and the another disk is HDD with Name **" Microsoft basic data "** ( **NTFS/exFAT/HPFS**) Master Boot Record

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       976769023   465.8 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 976769023 976766976 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

My question is any problem to have the disk with Microsoft Basic Data (exFAT) type in Linux. Is this partition will affect Ubuntu? I mean it's not primary Partition. but what should my normal disk (for normal files not systemfile ) type be in Linux?

> OS name : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
>
> OS type : 64-bit

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details, but this system I'm using now has `msftdata` and `msftres` partition(s) when I list details using `fdisk -l` and it doesn't worry me.  This box came with windows 11 that I've not yet deleted as I've not needed the space yet.  FYI:  My system is dual boot & I use only the Ubuntu *development* or LTS installs, the third is the unused windows 11  (*kept partially as it allowed me to use it for "Install Alongside" QA-test installs on this box before I made it my primary box*)

Comment: What are you asking? Are you asking if this partition will affect Ubuntu? *(It won't)* Or are you asking if Ubuntu can read/write to exFAT? *(It can)*. Or are you asking if you can convert one file system to another without formatting? *(No, not really)*. Or are you asking something else entirely? It's not clear what question you need answered or what problem you need solved. Can you please clarify? Because it's not clear what kind of answer you want, and we can give you a more specific answer if we can understand what you need to know.

Comment: First check if the HDD is formatted NTFS or ExFAT. If it is NTFS, you may need Windows to fix it if that partition gets corrupt in the future for some reason. Backup your personal files in any case. As you don't need compatibility between Windows and Ubuntu any more, the ext4 format will be better in the long run.